# cherrypy - Not returning the Object in response

Tags: python, rest, cherrypy, cherrypywsgiserver

I've a class "TestMap" at the REST Service Side.

Rest Service is Exposed using cherrypy like below:

```
class TestApi(object):

@serialize_content
def GET(self):
    pass

@serialize_content
def POST(self):
   pass
```

When the client sends POST request/ GET request to API, API calls internally a method which sends the object of TestMap class.

But in response, I don't receive an object, I receive a dictionary out of it. Can you please help me to return an object.

And that Object is needed as we need to call different methods on that object.

Thanks